# Does there exist a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that takes each value in $\mathbb{R}$ exactly two times?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that takes each value in $\mathbb{R}$ exactly two times?[image]

im not getting the red lines as how can postive value achieved 3 times .

Can anybody elaborate in detail  as im not getting in my head.

thanks u

Comment: Draw a graph. That will help.

Comment: @fredgoodman  HOW can i draw the graph??? here left side is postive and right side is negative  ..then  only two sign is changes

Comment: In the middle interval the function goes from zero to max and from max to zero again so that's why near zero the function will reach the same positive value twice (function is continuous). The same value will be reached on the left interval when function approaches zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that $c \in (a,b)$ is where $f$ achieves its positive maximum $f(c) = M$ on $[a,b]$. Then there is some $x\in (a,c)$ such that $f(x) = M/2$. Similarly, there is some $y\in (c,b)$ such that $f(y) = M/2$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Since $f$ is positive in $(-\infty,a)$ and negative in $(b,+\infty)$, there is some point $w\in (-\infty,a)$ such that $f(w) = 2M$ because $f$ is surjective. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $z \in (w,a)$ such that $f(z) = M/2$.

But then we have produced three distinct points where $f(z) = f(x) = f(y) = M/2$.

Comment: thanks  a lots @AOrtiz as i have found ur answer beautiful

Comment: here f(c)= M,,,

Comment: @lomber Corrected

Comment: @A0rtiz thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the maximum point on $[a,b]$ where $f(m)=M>0$.

The left interval is positive, let $c<a$ and $f(c)=W>0$

Let $T= \min(M,W)$.

Apply intermedidate value theorem on $(c,a)$, we can find a point in that interval attaining value $\frac{T}2$.

Apply intermedidate value theorem on $(a,m)$, we can find a point in that interval attaining value $\frac{T}2$.

Apply intermedidate value theorem on $(m,b)$, we can find a point in that interval attaining value $\frac{T}2$.

Hence it is achieved $3$ times.

Comment: thanks a lots @Siong Thye Goh

Answer (score 1):

Choose any number $y \in (0, \max_{[a, b]} f)$. Then $f(x) = y$ has at least two solutions on $(a, b)$ as a consequence of the intermediate value theorem.

Now because $f$ is nonnegative on $(-\infty, a)$ and blows up, continuity guarantees that $f(x) = y$ has at least one solution on this interval too.

So we have three total.

If you haven't yet, you really need to draw a graph of this scenario.

Comment: thanks a lots @user296602